# Properties of Direct Integral

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

I am wondering whether the following properties hold, and when not hold, can we require some conditions such that they hold?

(1) Direct integral v.s. induced representation

$Ind_{H}^{G}\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi} d\mu(\pi)\cong \int_{\hat{H}}Ind_{H}^{G}\mathcal{H}_{\pi} d\mu(\pi) $ as G-representation

(2) Direct integral v.s. contragredient representation (dual representation)

$\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{\vee} d\mu(\pi)\cong (\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi} d\mu(\pi))^{\vee} $ as H-representation

(3) Direct integral v.s. direct sum

$\int_{\hat{H}}\oplus_{i}\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{i} d\mu(\pi)\cong \oplus_{i}\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi}^{i} d\mu(\pi) $ as H-representation

(4) Direct integral v.s. Hom

$\int_{\hat{H}}Hom_{H}(\mathcal{H}_{\pi},\rho) d\mu(\pi)\cong Hom_{H}(\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi} d\mu(\pi),\rho) $ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

(5) Direct integral v.s. coinvariant

$\int_{\hat{H}}(\mathcal{H}_{\pi})_{T} d\mu(\pi)\cong (\int_{\hat{H}}\mathcal{H}_{\pi} d\mu(\pi))_{T} $ as $\mathbb{C}$-vector space

I will appreciate if you can provide the precise statements of above properties and references. Thank you all the time.